# Non-uniform distribution with uniform subsets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let $X=[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ be a random vector of binary-valued random variables, taking values in $\{0,1\}^n$.

Let $S(n,k)$ denote the set of all size $k$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Can anyone describe a joint distribution over $X$ such that each size $k$ subset $[X_{s(1)},\dots,X_{s(k)}], (s \in S(n,k), k=1,2,\dots,n-1)$ of the random vector $X$ is uniformly distributed over $\{0,1\}^{k}$, but $X$ is **not** uniformly distributed over $\{0,1\}^n$?

Comment: I think where it says $\{0,1\}^{n-1}$ you mean $\{0,1\}^k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform distribution over all vectors with an odd number of ones fits the bill.

Comment: Very clever! A simulation algorithm would be to take $ i \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(1,2,\dots,n)$, take $X_j \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2), (j \ne i)$ and set $X_i$ to 1 if $X_{-i}$ has an even number of ones, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @jesterII: Yes, but you don't need to randomize $i$; fixing e.g. $i=n$ is good enough.